# Почему не подключаются шрифты через LiveEdit?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webstorm

В webstorm есть LiveEdit. Установил в хром для него расширение JetBrains IDE Support.

Но все работает с ошибками - например, расширение не хочет отображать шрифты гугла + есть некоторые другие ошибки.

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить

[image: картинка с ошибкой]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте включить **Allow unsigned requests** в **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger** - должно помочь

Comment: действительно, частично решило проблему, кроме самой первой ошибки:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ну там просто URL некорректный, видимо. Попробуйте указать правильный путь относительно текущего HTML файла

Comment: У меня там 1 html файл и 2 css + 2 пустые папки: img и sourse. Из-за пустых папок может такое быть?

Comment: @Евгений, нет не может перепроверьте правильность `url`